# How to combine row in query mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
     PO.ITEM_NO,
     PO_NO,
     PO.DESCRIPT,
     PO.REM1,
     QTY 
FROM PODSCRP PO ,PRODUCT P 
WHERE P.ITEM_NO=PO.ITEM_NO AND PO.PO_NO ='PO170010'
```

[image: query result]

I want to get result :

```
if REM1=1 this will FOC1_QTY,
  REM1=2 FOC2_QTY,
  REM1=NULL is SALE_QTY
  and if not include REM1 VALUE 1 or 2, There is not FOC value so FOC1_QTY and FOC2_QTY must be 0.
```

I want to pull out the query like following table.

```
ITEM_NO  FOC1_QTY FOC2_QTY  SALE_QTY 
P00001   10       100           100
P00002   0        0             100
P00004   0        0             100
```

How to do sql query for above table..

Comment: Then, where does that FOC2_QYT come from?

Comment: Hi FOC2_QTY is come form where REM1= 2, this QTY must be FOC2_QTY @Mark

Comment: You have to explain the expected output in detail. Doesnt make sense.

Comment: sorry for my english skill, above query is what i get and i want to output below table..@Utsav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(ITEM_NO VARCHAR(10),REM1 INT,QTY INT)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES ('P00001',NULL,100),
                      ('P00001',1,10),
                      ('P00001',2,100)

SELECT  ITEM_NO
        ,[1] FOC1_QTY
        ,[2] FOC2_QTY
        ,[0] SALE_QTY
FROM    (
        SELECT ITEM_NO,ISNULL(REM1,0)REM1,QTY FROM @T
        )A
PIVOT(
     MAX(QTY) FOR REM1 IN([1],[2],[0] ) 
     )PVT
```

Comment: use instead A PIVOT , my table?